# R:Identifying points inside a circle and calculating a new column based on two dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having a sample dataset like below

```
   Town_From<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C")
   Town_To<-c("B","C","D","C","D","D")
   Distance<-c(10,5,18,17,20,21)
   Df<-data.frame(Town_From,Town_To,Distance)

 Town_From Town_To  Distance 
    A         B        10     
    A         C         5     
    A         D        18     
    B         C        17     
    B         D        20     
    C         D        21
```

I have another data frame (Df2) which has the population values

```
   Town<-c("A","B","C","D")
   Population<-c(1000,800,500,200)
   Df2<-data.frame(Town,Population)

  Town  Population
   A     1000
   B      800
   C      500
   D      200
```

What I need is a calculated column as "Pop_within_Distance"

```
  Town_From Town_To  Distance  Pop_within_Distance
    A         B        10      2300
    A         C         5      1500
    A         D        18      2500
    B         C        17      1300
    B         D        20      1500
    C         D        21      700
```

Town_From is my Origin and I need to calculate the sum of population of the towns which lie within the radius of "Town_From" and "Town_To" as "Pop_within_Distance"

For example,

In 1st row,  "Pop_within_Distance" = Pop_A + Pop_B + Pop_C =1000+800+500=2300 (This is because, Towns A,B & C lies within the circle with the radius 10 from Town A)

In 4th row, "Pop_within_Distance" = Pop_B + Pop_C = 800+500=1300
(This is because, Only Towns B & C lies within the circle with the radius 17 from Town B)

How can I calculate this in R?

Comment: This isn't really a coding problem; it's a math problem.

Comment: @ulfelder it's prbly homework. OP: If so (even if not) what have you tried that failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `dplyr` given that we first convert your data frames so that the `Town_From`, `Town_To`, and `Town` columns are characters and not factors (or they are factors with the same levels):

```
library(dplyr)
Df <- Df %>% left_join(Df2,by=c("Town_To"="Town")) %>% 
             group_by(Town_From) %>% 
             arrange(Distance) %>% 
             mutate(Pop_within_Distance=cumsum(Population)+Df2$Population[Df2$Town %in% Town_From]) %>%
             select(-Population) %>% arrange(Town_From,Town_To)
##Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
##Groups: Town_From [3]
##
##  Town_From Town_To Distance Pop_within_Distance
##      <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>               <dbl>
##1         A       B       10                2300
##2         A       C        5                1500
##3         A       D       18                2500
##4         B       C       17                1300
##5         B       D       20                1500
##6         C       D       21                 700
```

Notes:

1. First `left_join` the two data frames by `Town_To` in `Df` and `Town` in `Df2` so that we get this intermediate result:

   ```
     Town_From Town_To Distance Population
   1         A       B       10        800
   2         A       C        5        500
   3         A       D       18        200
   4         B       C       17        500
   5         B       D       20        200
   6         C       D       21        200
   ```
2. Group by `Town_From` and sort the table by `Distance` using `arrange`. The point here is that we can now use `cumsum` on `Population` to compute the sum population for towns with distances less than or equal to the current row.
3. Then create the `Pop_within_Distance` column using `mutate` with this computation adding the origin town's (i.e., `Town_From`) population from `Df2`.
4. Finally, remove the `Population` column and return the original order of rows.

**Data:**

```
Df <- structure(list(Town_From = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), Town_To = c("B", 
"C", "D", "C", "D", "D"), Distance = c(10, 5, 18, 17, 20, 21)), .Names = c("Town_From", 
"Town_To", "Distance"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
##  Town_From Town_To Distance
##1         A       B       10
##2         A       C        5
##3         A       D       18
##4         B       C       17
##5         B       D       20
##6         C       D       21

Df2 <- structure(list(Town = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Population = c(1000, 
800, 500, 200)), .Names = c("Town", "Population"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
##  Town Population
##1    A       1000
##2    B        800
##3    C        500
##4    D        200
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the descriptive answer. I did not think about sorting and getting the cumulative sum.Rather, I was thinking about how to identify points inside the circle with the distances. This was a simple and very helpful solution.